# Reading pdf form fields in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, adobe, acrobat

Hello I am trying to use vba to read the field names of a pdf form. But the obstacle is whenever I try to run the code, it returns this error
[click here to preview the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWsZV.png)

**Run time error : "-2147319322 (800280rb)

Automation Error, Element no found**

Extra Note:

1. I have installed Adobe Acrobat Pro
2. I have made references to the required libraries: AFormOut 1.0 Type Library and Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library.
   [link to the screen capture of the referred libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ6fi.png)

Here is my code:

```
Sub read_pdf_form_fields()

Dim aApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim avdoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim pdfformfile As String
Dim pdf_form As AFORMAUTLib.AFormApp
Dim pdf_form_flds As AFORMAUTLib.Fields
Dim pdf_form_fld As AFORMAUTLib.Field
Dim pdf_form_file As String

Set aApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set avdoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If avdoc.Open(Range("directory").Value, "") = True 
    'MsgBox True

    avdoc.BringToFront
    aApp.Hide

    Set pdf_form = CreateObject("AFORMAUT.App")
    Set pdf_form_flds = pdf_form.Fields


    For Each pdf_form_fld In pdf_form_flds 'the error happens here

        With pdf_form_fld

             Debug.Print .Name & "| " & .Type & " |" & .Value

        End With
    Next pdf_form_fld

Else
    Debug.Print False

End If
aApp.Exit

Set aApp = Nothing
Set avdoc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It look like you are missing a "then" here If

```
If avdoc.Open(Range("directory").Value, "") = True
```

should be

```
If avdoc.Open(Range("directory").Value, "") = True Then
```

EDIT: also Range("directory").Value from what you have provided, is nothing as to my knowledge, Range needs to
A. have a cell reference i.e. Range("A1")
or
B. refer to a Dim like so

```
Dim directory As Integer'//idk what Var type you are intending to use
Range("A" & directory)
```